# How to gain the facility of snapping when multiple points are selected

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop

I have created a fishnet label(square 961 points) centering a point in other layer in arc map but the fishnet is deviated from the intended center.
Now i want to place the midpoint of labels on the intended center by selecting all the labels.
But when i select all label points, i do not get the facility of snapping whereas i put the midpoint of the labels on top of the intended center accurately.
Whenever i zoom the map i found midpoint of fishnet labels and intended center did no match.

```
                                Present situation
```

[image: Present situation]

```
                                Wanted situation
```

[image: Wanted situation]

Both are in the same coordinate system.
How can i get rid of this situation .

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?

Comment: I am in arc gis 10.1

Comment: Have you looked at [**Spatial Adjustment**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m800000030000000) and/or simply determining the precise coordinates of your red point and using that to create a new fishnet?  Also, are both layers in the same coordinate system?  Be sure to update your question using the edit button with any extra information that you use in your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this isn't as simple as you'd like, but it will give you the midpoint your looking for.

Along the bottom of your fishnet you could create a polyline the width of your fishnet.  The snapping tool will pick up on the midpoint of your line, start another line from that point.  Make sure the second line is the height of you fishnet and you should have the center when the snapping tool locks onto the midpoint.